# Temporarily change format of a date column in SQL Query output MM/YY -> MM/DD/YYYY

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have data on my SQL Server that is formatted like so:

```
06/21
```

MM/YY

I would like to manipulate it so that all the dates are displayed as MM/DD/YYYY. So as the previous example it would look like:

```
06/01/2021
```

I was wondering if there is some sort of function that I can run in my query to display the date column differently in my output? I don't want to actually alter the way in which the Column is formatted on the back end, I just want to change how it is presented to the user in the results of a single query.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: WHat is your date saved as in the DB?  Is it just saved as varchar?  Also do you want all the dates to be set to the first of the month?  (since you dont have the day saved in the db)?  Anytime you just seelct the date it wont edit the underlying data in the table

Comment: Fix your data so you are using proper `date`s!

Comment: Y2K called and wondered why you were still using 2 digit years.

Comment: @Brad yes they are saved as varchar because we are scraping this data and it often comes in different formats. Yes, need these to all be the first of the month. So I convert these all to date type?

Comment: Date or datetime @infosec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `STUFF`

```
declare @var varchar(64) = '06/21 '
select stuff(@var,4,0,'01/20')
```

So for your table.

```
select stuff(yourColumn,4,0,'01/20')
From yourTable
```

Comment: How would I do this for all values in a column without doing this one by one?

Comment: Just replace @var with your column name

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `/` with `01/20`:

```
declare @yourDate varchar(10) = '06/21'
select replace(@yourDate ,'/','/01/20')
```

Result:

[image]

But it is probably wiser to cast it to a proper `date` type:

```
declare @yourDate varchar(10) = '06/21'
select cast(replace(@yourDate ,'/','/01/20') as date)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this solution 
it works with all years 1998, .. 2000,2001 ...

```
declare @theDate varchar(10) = '06/21'
select convert(date,'01/'+ @theDate ,3)
```